# How do I ensure a Django Channels message is sent immediately without delay?

Tags: django, django-channels

The idea is to run a background task on the `worker.connect` worker. While executing the task, I would like to send its progress to a connected client via the notifications Group.

The problem: the messages sent to the notifications Group are delayed until the task on the worker is finished. So: both messages 'Start' and 'Stop' appear simultaneously on the client, after a delay of 5 seconds (`sleep(5)`). I would expect the message 'Start', followed by a 5sec delay, followed by the message 'Stop'. Any idea why this is not the case?

I have the following three processes running:

- `daphne tests.asgi:channel_layer`
- `python manage.py runworker --exclude-channel=worker.connect`
- `python manage.py runworker --only-channel=worker.connect`

In `views.py`:

```
def run(request, pk):
    Channel('worker.connect').send({'pk': pk})
    return HttpResponse(status=200)
```

In `consumers.py`:

```
def ws_connect(message):
    Group('notifications').add(message.reply_channel)
    message.reply_channel.send({"accept": True})

def worker_connect(message):
    run_channel(message)
```

In `views.py`:

```
def run_channel(message):
    Group('notifications').send({'text': 'Start'})
    sleep(5)
    Group('notifications').send({'text': 'Stop'})
```

`routing.py`

```
channel_routing = {
    'websocket.connect': consumers.ws_connect,
    'worker.connect': consumers.worker_connect,
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add `immediately=True` as argument to the `send` function. According to the source:

> Sends are delayed until consumer completion. To override this, you may pass immediately=True.

https://github.com/django/channels/blob/master/channels/channel.py#L32

Comment: Is this still applicable for Django Channels 2.0? I cannot see immediately arg in the help documents @Sander