# display progress bar for ffmpeg process in front-end

Tags: django, ffmpeg, content-management-system, progress-bar, transcode

I'm working on a cms project in which i have to transcode video files using ffmpeg. The transcoding proecss has been successfull. But i have to display the progress of the ffmpeg process in front-end. I tried pytranscoder,which failed to display the progress. Any help will be appreciated.

Note: I'm using Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: What do you mean by frontend? Is it a python GUI or django admin or a website etc.

Comment: it is a website. I want the progress bar to be displayed in the web page where i select the video.After selecting the video which i want to transcode,the progress bar should be displayed in the same page itself.

Comment: Unfortunately standard HTTP requests are a 1 time deal, so after the request-response cycle you don't get any more info. You could implement some sort of polling on the frontend to continually request the status every few seconds and imitate a realtime progress bar? Or you could use websockets but i'm not overly familiar with that. Here is a link to a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43284460/using-django-channels-for-a-progress-indicator

Comment: Thanks. Let me check it out. My actual problem lies where im unable to get the ffmpeg stdout to python.