# Immediately sending messages using Django Channels

Tags: python, django, websocket, django-channels

I have a long-running operation that is kicked off by a message from a websocket and I would like my server to send a confirmation to the client with when the operation was started and when it was ended.

This is essentially the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41684282/how-do-i-ensure-a-django-channels-message-is-sent-immediately-without-delay) but there was no useful answer. I tried `await self.send(data, immediately=True)` but got an error because it seems `immediately` is either no longer supported or doesn't work in the async version or something.

I really do not want to screw around with setting up channel layers and Redis and having yet another thing to configure that will inevitably break, or worse, have to set up Celery in WSL and deal with all my testing happening in a separate VM. If this isn't possible with just Channels, I am perfectly happy with that so no need to explain how to set it up using a third-party library (if you think others might find it useful, by all means go ahead).

Comment: I ran into the same issue -- I had to switch from using a synchronous Consumer to an async Consumer to get the desired behavior.